# Как сделать бинды на разные вкладки ttk.Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Нужно сделать бинды для двух вкладок, находящихся в ttk.Notebook, но никак не получается их туда присобачить. Пробовал делать бинды на Treeview, которое внутри вкладки, но чтобы бинд заработал, надо нажать на само Дерево, а это не подходит, т.к. Treeview занимает не все пространство. Подскажите, как сделать разные бинды для каждой вкладки

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(frame)
tree1["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree1.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree1.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(frame2)
tree2["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree2.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree2.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.pack()
note.add(frame, text="page1")
note.add(frame2, text="page2")
```

PS Простите если код корявый(писал с телефона)

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, минимальный пример для опробования :)

Comment: @gil9red, код добавлен. Извините что без комментов и тд, писал на коленке с телефона

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите "прибиндить"? Какое должно быть действие на какое событие?

Comment: @insolor, действия  должны происходить при нажатии Ctontrol+A. К примеру пускай выводит какое-нибудь слово, но главное разные слова для каждой вкладки Notebook

Comment: Можно попробовать bind ко всему окну, либо bind_all, потом при срабатывании проверять какая вкладка активна, и разные действия в зависимости от этого выполнять. Либо биндиться не на дерево, а на фрейм, в котором оно расположено.

Comment: @insolor, пробовал, бинд в случае с Контейнером не всегда срабатывал. Применял и бинды ко всему окну, но не знаю как проверить какая вкладка открыта. Также пробовал делать функцию, срабатывающую на переключение вкладок(через событие <NotebookTabChange>), но событие не срабатывало.

Comment: `"<<NotebookTabChanged>>"` должно быть в двойных угловых скобках.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо огромное. Поменял на двойные угловые скобки и всё стало работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал всё таким способом:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

note_bind = 0

root = tk.Tk()

note = ttk.Notebook(root)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(frame)
tree1["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree1.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree1.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.pack()

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(frame2)
tree2["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree2.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree2.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
tree2.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
tree2.pack()

note.add(frame, text="page1")
note.add(frame2, text="page2")
note.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", lambda event: bind(root))

note.pack()

def bind(root):
    global note_bind
    if note_bind == 0:
        root.bind("<Control-Key-a>", lambda event: print('Hi'))
        note_bind = 1
    else:
        root.bind("<Control-Key-a>", lambda event: print('Hello'))
        note_bind = 0

root.mainloop()
```